# How to display again the autocomplete list of textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a textbox where i write email addresses. When i press a character for first time in textbox, it displays the autocomplete list. After first address i put a semicolon, and then i write the next address, but it doesn't displays the autocomplete list, is there some method to display it again?

Edit: in the onload method of my form i have:

```
    SendTo_tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    SendTo_tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    SendTo_tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("example1@test.net")
    SendTo_tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("test1@example.com")
```

Comment: What do you have so far (I mean the code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are going for the outlook style approach where after the semi colon you want the autocomplete list to re-appear so you can select a new value.  The out of the box autocomplete functionality on the textbox does not provide the ability to do this.  You can create your own relatively easily or find a control that supports the feature you want.  The link below has a pretty functional C# example:

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/multivalue-autocomplete-winforms-textbox-for-tagging/

With the code available on codeplex:
http://autocompletetexboxcs.codeplex.com/